# What's the purpose of Riak secondary index data type?

Tags: indexing, riak

There is data type concept for secondary index in Riak, I am not sure why we need this data type? Because the index looks just like kind of categories for stored data object.

I did not find any document for this.

Answer (score 2):

2i (secondary indexes) allows you to reference an object in Riak via ... an index. Meaning something other than your key. You can also perform range queries using a secondary index.

See: [How to query nested keys in Riak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708368/how-to-query-nested-keys-in-riak)

And our documentation at: 
http://wiki.basho.com/Secondary-Indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, Secondary Index objects allow you to model one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relationships in Riak, in a fairly efficient manner.

Take a look at the following discussions about data modeling relationships in Riak, to help shed light on secondary indexes:

- [How to structure data in Riak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052154/how-to-structure-data-in-riak/13002044#13002044)
- [Links in Riak: what can they do/not do, compared to graph databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752036/links-in-riak-what-can-they-do-not-do-compared-to-graph-databases/13001620#13001620)
- [Which clustered NoSQL DB for a Message Storing purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286080/which-clustered-nosql-db-for-a-message-storing-purpose/13001495#13001495)